# Latest version of libnfc can't find the reader

Tags: c, compilation, nfc

I just compiled the latest version of libnfc, but it (nfc-poll & nfc-list) wont find my reader.

Anyone had this problem and know hows to solve it?

Old version:

```
nfc_list.exe use libnfc 1.3.9
Connected to NFC reader: ACS ACR122 0 / ACR122U210 - PN532 v1.6 (0x07)
1 ISO14443A passive target(s) was found:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  02
       UID (NFCID1): 91  e8  1c  57
      SAK (SEL_RES): 18
```

New version:

```
nfc-list.exe uses libnfc 1.7.1
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using arygon driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn532_uart driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using ACR122S driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn53x_usb driver
No NFC device found.
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that, while it's connected to the usb port, it needed to be compiled with `LIBNFC_DRIVER_ACR122_PCSC` instead of the `LIBNFC_DRIVER_ACR122_USB` flag.

This solved the problem for me.

```
nfc-list.exe uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC device: ACS ACR122 0 / ACR122U210 opened
1 ISO14443A passive target(s) found:
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  02
       UID (NFCID1): 91  e8  1c  57
      SAK (SEL_RES): 18
```